# How to group data in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Task.select('task_name, id, COUNT(*) AS cnt').group(:task_name).having('cnt > 1')
```

What's wrong with this query I getting error like :  **PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "cnt" does not exist**

Please Help me in this query.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What does .to_sql return for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (note the duplication of the function in the having clause):

```
Task.select("..., COUNT(*) AS cnt").group("...").having("COUNT(*) > 1")
```

From: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-having/